# SQL Server: Updating/Replacing live db (only schema) with testing db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases `abc` and `abcTesting`, the first one is live (locally) and the second one is being used for testing purposes, now is the time to merge/replace/update the existing database with the `abcTesting` db which obviously contains (new columns/tables/or any new relations). I do not want to change the data already in `abc` but I want the new changes made in `abceTesting` db to be applied in the existing db. How do I do this?

1: Take schema of existing `abcTesting` db and then replace it with `abc`

2: rename the new Testing db with previous one? (lol obviously no)

Comment: if you just replace one DB with another, you'll lose all your live data. During development you should have been writing (or generating, based on your GUI-led changes) DDL scripts which applied to your test database. Then when they were correct you should have source-controlled them so you could re-use them later on the live system. You would then be able to run those scripts on the live database to make the same structural changes. After that you'd run any scripts needed to change data (e.g. add more reference data, default values, or settings etc) without affecting the user-generated data.

Comment: Of course if you didn't maintain a proper list of the schema changes you were making, you'll have to go back, work out what you changed, and retrospectively write scripts which can be used to apply the same changes to the live system. Then you take a backup of the live system, restore it somewhere, and test that your change scripts definitely work, before you apply them to live. Then before you apply to live, you take the system offline to users, back it up again, and only then apply your change scripts, so you don't screw up.

Comment: P.S. Luckily there are tools available (including in Visual Studio and other products) which can help you automatically locate the differences between two databases' schema definitions and generate the necessary DDL scripts to migrate one to another. But in terms of any data changes required, you'll have to carefully work that out yourself according to your business requirements etc. Good luck.

Comment: @ADyson that sounds like I am ******

Comment: This might help you a bit if you haven't been tracking your changes properly: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/ssdt/ - see the "Schema and Data Compare" feature